# Why will my Button not add a row to my TableLayout?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tablelayout

I am trying to add a new row to my TableLayout when I click the "addSplitButton". When I click the button though, it doesn't do anything that I can see. If someone can look at my code and point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class TimerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//counter created to increment for row number.
int counter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    //Initiate the method for adding a split.
    initAddSplit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.timer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void initAddSplit(){
    Button addSplit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addSplitButton);
    addSplit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.timerSplits);
              TableRow tr = new TableRow(TimerActivity.this);
              LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              tr.setLayoutParams(lp);

              EditText etLeft = new EditText(TimerActivity.this);
              etLeft.setLayoutParams(lp);
              etLeft.setText("Split Name " + counter);

              TextView tvCenter = new TextView(TimerActivity.this);
              tvCenter.setLayoutParams(lp);
              tvCenter.setText("00:00.00");

              TextView tvRight = new TextView(TimerActivity.this);
              tvRight.setLayoutParams(lp);
              tvRight.setText("00:00:00.00");

              tr.addView(etLeft);
              tr.addView(tvCenter);
              tr.addView(tvRight);

              tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying specifying Tablelayout or tablerow layout param in this line instead of making it generic (coming from linear layout)

```
 LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              tr.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `invalidate()` on the `TableLayout` after you change it.

Comment: so would I just put tl.invalidate(); after the tl.addView line? Sorry, kind of new to eclipse so don't really know my way around it just yet.